# Compare two regression models in R

Tags: r, regression

```
age25=subset(juul,juul[,"age"]>25.00)## create a subset of age greater than 25
modelgf=lm(age25[,"igf1"]~age25[,"age"])
age20=subset(juul,juul[,"age"]<20.00)
modelgf2=lm(age20[,"igf1"]~age20[,"age"])
```

I tried to compare the `modelgf` and `modelgf2` models using `anova(m1,m2)`. However, I get a warning message:

```
In anova.lmlist(object, ...) :
  models with response ‘"age20[, \"igf1\"]"’ removed because response differs from model 1
```

Are there any other ways to compare these two models?

Comment: This is just wrong. You should instead create a factor variable for age categories and run on regression.

Comment: It's difficult to help without a sample of your data to make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why discretize a continuous variable at all? This is almost always a bad idea... https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/230756/176202

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
# Dummy for Age>25
juul[,"ageCat25"] <- juul[,"ageCat"] > 25.00
# Collinear dummy for Age<20
juul[,"ageCat20"] <- ifelse(!juul[,"ageCat25"] & juul[,"age"]<20.00, TRUE, juul[,"ageCat25"])
m1 <- lm(foo ~ ageCat25, juul)
m2 <- lm(foo ~ ageCat20, juul)
anova(m1,m2)
```

Interpretation left to the OP.

Comment: If you are comparing two different models with `anova` they need to be built on the same data.